# The amplitude of oscillations in sound waves

Tags: waves, acoustics, measurements

1. How can the amplitude of molecules displacement be measured in a sound wave?
2. How can the amplitude of the pressure fluctuation be measured in a sound wave?
3. What are the difference between these two amplitudes?

Comment: Did you see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_measurements? It's not the best wiki page but it summarizes some of the units. Curiously, a lot of the literature on absolute calibration seems to be rather old. Look at these: http://www.bksv.com/doc/TechnicalReview1964-4.pdf, http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/25/jresv25n5p489_A1b.pdf. Thanks for asking!

Comment: This flashlet will help you to visualize sound waves.http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/Particle%20Wave.swf

Comment: I think that there is an interesting question hiding here, but it needs some more improvement...

Comment: Isn't the molecule displacement related to the wavelength since sound waves are compressional longitudinal waves?  The pressure can be measured with a pressure sensor (there are numerous different types), though I think there are ones specifically made for pressure waves in air, water, and solids.  Sound wave also occur in plasmas like the solar wind, but they are called ion acoustic waves and slow (and fast) magnetosonic waves.  We measure these using electromagnetic fields and particle detectors (to measure density and pressure).